# Calculating the median of data where some values contain "<"

Tags: vba, excel

I need to calculate the median of a set of measurements where in some cases a value was measured, and in some cases the value was below detection (indicated by "<" sign followed by the detection limit, e.g. <1)

Here are some examples of cases that I'm encountering:

> 2.0; 3.0; <1.0; 4.0 --> median = 2.5
>     1.0; <0.5; <0.5 --> median = <0.5
>     1.0; 1.0; <0.5; <0.5 --> median = <0.75

I'm a little stumped about doing this in excel VBA.
How can I do math with the values that have a "<" sign while still keeping track of the "<"?

Any input is much appreciated -- thanks!

Comment: One approach is to split out the modifier into a separate column from the numbers, then do the math on the numbers only. Otherwise, you could write a VBA function to do the calculations which would strip the modifier(s) and then re-add them to the final calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something I use:

```
Public Function DoAvg(rng As Range)
  DoAvg = Parse(rng, "Average")
End Function

Public Function DoMedian(rng As Range)
  DoMedian = Parse(rng, "Median")
End Function


'This does the work...
Private Function Parse(rng As Range, CalcType As String)

Dim rv, arr() As Single, mods As String, i As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim tmp, m

  For Each c In rng.Cells
    tmp = Replace(Trim(c.Value), " ", "")
    If tmp Like "<*" Or tmp Like ">*" Then
        m = Left(tmp, 1)
        If Not InStr(mods, m) > 0 Then mods = mods & m
        tmp = Right(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)
    End If

    If IsNumeric(tmp) And tmp <> "" Then
      i = i + 1
      ReDim Preserve arr(1 To i)
      arr(i) = tmp
    End If
  Next c

  If i > 1 Then
      rv = CallByName(Application.WorksheetFunction, CalcType, VbGet, arr)
      Parse = IIf(mods <> "", mods, "") & rv
  Else
      Parse = ""
  End if

End Function
```

Comment: @brettdj - I assumed that was a typo in the original question. All those groups have at least one modifier.